# How many $3$-digit positive integers can be represented as the sum of exactly nine different powers of $2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How many $3$-digit positive integers can be represented as the sum of
>   exactly nine different powers of $2$?

What does this question mean? Is the sum of $9$ different powers of $2$ like $2^1+2^2+...2^9$?  Then it must be $>1000$.

Comment: You also have $2^0=1$

Comment: Forgot to mention that the answer is 5.Having 2^0+...2^8 means that there is 1 sum,what is another 4?Never thought about the 0 power tho.

Answer (score 2):

Since $2^{10}$ has four digits, these numbers must be of the form
$$2^0 + 2^1 + \dots + 2^9 - 2^a = 1023 - 2^a$$
for some $a = 0, \dots, 9$.
The condition that our number should have three digits is equivalent to $2^a \geq 24$, or $a \geq 5$. Therefore there are **five** possibilities, corresponding to $a = 5, \dots, 9$.

Comment: Thx,so the “sum" actually means that it include subtractions?I thought sum only means additions.So the sum also means... the additions of negative integers...

Comment: No, the sum only involves additions. But we know that nine of the ten numbers $2^0, 2^1, \dots, 2^9$ appear in the sum. So the sum is equal to the sum of all ten minus the one that's left out. Thinking about it that way makes it easier to count the number of possibilities.

Comment: I see...now I understand it completely.

Comment: Good. One more thing I didn't mention in the solution is how I found $1023$. I didn't need to add all those powers of $2$. It's $2^{10} - 1$.